# Magic v1 does not support record headers - Appdynamics Adding SingularityHeader

Tags: apache-kafka, header, appdynamics

I am facing `Magic v1 does not support record headers` while consuming the messages form Kafka. I understand this comes for the older kafka client version. But in my case AppDynamics is injecting a SingularityHeader as given below -

```
singularityheader: [110, 111, 116, 120, 100, 101, 116, 101, 99, 116, 61, 116, 114, 117, 101, 42, 99, 116, 114, 108, 103, 117, 105, 100, 61, 49, 53, 54, 54, 50, 55, 55, 56, 49, 52, 42, 97, 112, 112, 73, 100, 61, 50, 56, 48, 42, 110, 111, 100, 101, 105, 100, 61, 50, 50, 54, 52, 48, 57, 55]
```

`Kafka Client Version - 0.10.2.0.` I need suggestions here other than Upgrading Kafka Client version to 0.11.x from 0.10.2.0 (that is not an option). Is there a way to disable this from APPD itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for an answer here. This is resolved by unchecking the Extended  tracking option for kafka in AppDynamics Console. The option will be there in Automatic Backend Discovery. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable default Kafka configuration on "Backend Detection" page
2. Define a new "Custom Exit Point" with the last class and method which you see on the call graphs before Kafka exit call
3. Don't forget to click on "Is High Volume" checkbox.